# Chrome's "Disable Javascript" feature resets on refresh

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

While testing no-js fallbacks on my site in Chrome 37.0, I open up Developer Tools, hit the Settings icon and check "Disable Javascript". But then when I refresh to see my no-js site, "Disable Javascript" becomes unchecked and my scripts still run. (Changing chrome://settings/ still works, though.)

- Has anyone else seen this issue? Is it a bug with 37.0?
- How do I fix this?

Comment: Works fine on 37.0.2062.124 m

Comment: @judgeja 37.0.2062.124 m, that's what I got. So it's not a version issue I guess... I don't know what else. It does it on both my localhost as well as on stackoverflow.com... Chrome had this exact same issue many months back so I figured it was one of those nightly bugs that made it through.

Comment: Same problem with this version: 39.0.2171.95 m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I haven't found any references to this being a documented bug (not everybody seems to be experiencing this, but several folks have on various versions), I have found a good enough fix:

Open your page using `incognito mode` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) and "Disable Javascript" should work correctly.

Comment: Is there an alternative to this? Some users prefer to keep their history recorded and have cookies stored on websites.

Comment: @DominatorX yeah, alternative would be nice. Though, the history thing doesn't really bug me as I'm only testing one page at a time, and it's only testing the no-js fallbacks. Not really with you on the cookies, as those won't work in a no-js environment anyways. But still, lots of reasons to not want to pull up incognito mode just to test something that Chrome is *supposed* to be able to do anyways.